# Crear rutas en React con wounter

Tags: reactjs

Mi problema es que quiero utilizar la libreria wounter para crear mis rutas pero siguiendo el tutorial, en mi codigo sale el siguiente error :"Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it."

este es mi codigo:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'
import { Link, Route } from 'wouter'
import { Cuadro } from './pages/cuadro.tsx'

const Router = () => (
  <>
    <Link href='/cuadro/1'>
     <a>ASDDSAD</a>
    </Link> 
    <Route path='/' component={App} />
    <Route path='/cuadro/:id'>
       {params => <Cuadro id={params.id} />}
   </Route>
  </>

  )
  ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Router />
  </React.StrictMode>
   )
```